# directx11 add glow to DrawLine 2d

Tags: c++, directx, direct2d

Im drawing a 2d line how would i add a glow effect to it?

```
auto renderer::draw_line(point<float> const& start_point, point<float> const& end_point, float const stroke_width, color const& stroke_color) -> void {

    brush->SetColor(D2D1::ColorF(stroke_color.r, stroke_color.g, stroke_color.b, stroke_color.a));

    device_context_d2d1->DrawLine(
        D2D1::Point2F(start_point.x + offsetX, start_point.y + offsetY),
        D2D1::Point2F(end_point.x + offsetX, end_point.y + offsetY),
        brush.get(), stroke_width
    );

}
```

I think it has something todo with this function

```
ID2D1Effect* shadowEffect;
device_context_d2d1->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1Shadow, &shadowEffect);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply [Gaussian blur effect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706338(v=vs.85).aspx) (that is actually used in shadow effect), then (optionally) [apply Brightness effect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706315(v=vs.85).aspx) to blurred image and then finally draw blurred image on top of original line image.

[image: blurred line]

Comment: Not 100% sure on how you mean. wouldnt that just blur my line and nothing more?

Comment: Yes, but that is how typically all those glow effects work, take a "glowing" portion of the image (line in this case), blur it and draw on top of original image (maybe with adjusted brightness). If you turn blurred image color to black and draw original image on top of it you will get a shadow effect.

Comment: Thanks for the info, im a little confused on how to apply the blur to the line because `SetInput` takes a image? also how would i blur just one side is there some kind of region function in directx11?

Comment: Yes, you render line to a 2d texture, then apply blur and it gives you another 2d texture. As for region you can always use alpha channel.